# Gulp doesn't create css file

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, postcss

Gulp doesn't create css file from scss file.
I've been searching for solution for quite some time and I didn't find it.
Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var shortColor = require('postcss-short-color');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
var shortcss = require('postcss-short');
var sass =require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    var plugins = [
    sass,
    shortColor,
    shortcss,
    cssnext,
    autoprefixer({browsers: ['> 1%'], cascade: false})
  ];

  return gulp.src('./base/style.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(postcss(plugins))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles' , function(){
    gulp.watch('**/*.scss' , ['default'])
});
```

I don't know what's wrong :(
By the way, sorry for my English.

Comment: Try changing the `dest` to `./css/`

Comment: Nothing, already tried this :(

Comment: Check to see if it made a `css` folder at the root directory (e.g. C:\ if Windows).

Comment: Can you post your directory structure?

Comment: what about `gulp.dest('css')`, share folder structure if this doesnt work

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/7nJ58

Comment: @LastShadowPL which is your scss src directory? 'base ' or 'css', in the screen shot 'css' folder has the style.scss and 'base' is empty

Comment: /css/ i source and dest

Comment: return gulp.src('./css/style.scss')
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(postcss(plugins))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .on('error', console.error.bind(console));
});

gulp.task('watch:styles' , function(){
    gulp.watch('**/*.scss' , ['default'])
});